# Access DbContext from Inside of a Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, dbcontext

In a Controller, we can do this to inject the DbContext in to the Controller.  This works fine.

```
public class HockeyPlayer : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public HockeyPlayer(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

However; one thing I have never been able to do is to inject (or access) DbContext in a class file.

For example, say I have a class named HockeyPlayerData.

```
public class HockeyPlayerData
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public HockeyPlayerData(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

This throws an error when I try to use _context (Object reference not set to an instance of the object).

```
var db_query = _context.Set<HockeyPlayer>().FromSqlRaw("execute dbo.GetHockeyPlayer {0}, {1}", 0, 
userid).ToList();
```

The only way I can get it to work is to pass in DbContext to the class or each method.
For example:

```
HockeyPlayerData hp = new HockeyPlayerData(_context);
hp.GetPlayerData();
```

Or

```
HockeyPlayerData hp = new HockeyPlayerData();
hp.GetPlayerData(_context);
```

I really don't like that but I am also not sure if it is necessarily wrong.  Seems each class
should be able to easily access the database like the controllers do.  I have read quite a bit about this but I haven't really gotten anywhere.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Some of you wanted more code.  Does this help?  I mean this is basically it.  You can see I am trying to do injection at the top.  But when I run the application I get an error when I try to fill the model (Hockey Player) with data (Object reference not set to instance of the object) at _dbcontext.Set.

```
public class HockeyPlayerData
{
    public static MyDbContext _dbcontext;

    public HockeyPlayerData(MyDbContext db)
    {
        _dbcontext = db;
    }


    public string GetHockeyPlayerData(string userid)
    {
        string firstname = "";
        var query = _dbcontext.Set<HockeyPlayer>().FromSqlRaw("execute 
        dbo.GetHockeyPlayer {0}, {1}", 0, Convert.ToInt32(userid)).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < query.Count; i++)
        {
            firstname = query[i].FirstName;
        }

    return firstname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Passing a DbContext to a service is 100% possible and something extremely common.

Comment: Agree with @CamiloTerevinto, we need some sample code. Your _context.Set<HockeyPlayer> sample does not match with HockeyPlayerData above, so it's hard to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I updated the post.  See if that helps.  Remember, it works fine if I pass DbCoontext in from the Controller.  But when I try to inject, it does not.

Comment: Please add a complete example. How do you get an instance of HockeyPlayerData in the first place? Also, that code doesn't compile so [edit] your question and include the actual code, from the controller to the service and the calls

Answer (score 1):

You should resolve your class using dependency injection rather than creating an instance using the `new` operator. Here is an example that uses a [ServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for dependency injection:

```
public class HockeyPlayerData : IHockeyPlayerData
{
 private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public HockeyPlayerData(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
var provider = ServiceCollection()
    .AddTransient<IHockeyPlayerData, HockeyPlayerData >()
    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString))
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var hockeyPlayerData = provider.GetService<IHockeyProviderData>();
```

I would suggest reading up on the [Dependency Inversion Principal](https://stackify.com/dependency-inversion-principle/). Also, from the way you are using Entity Framework (using `FromSQLRaw` to retreive data), I think you may benefit for reading Entity Framework's [Getting Started Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli).

If your `MyDbContext` class has a DBSet like:

```
class MyDbContext
{
    public DbSet<PlayerData> PlayerData { get; set; }
}
```

You can use EF to do the query rather than generating raw SQL. For example:

```
var data = await context.PlayerData.Where(p => p.PlayerDataID == id).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: How do you know this is not what the OP is doing? This is just guessing, the second code snippet already shows `MyDbContext` being injected.

Comment: Yeah it shows it being injected but it throws an error (Object reference not set to an instance of the object).  If I pass in DbContext then it is fine.   The injected way acts like it injects it but then it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to circumvent the dependency container, sometimes nececsary if you need more control of the memory handling of the DbContext.

normally you would have a startup looking like this,
regular example:

```cs
// startup.cs - OnConfigure Method 
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("/*Connection string here*/"));
services.AddScoped<IAppService, AppService>();

// class which uses the dbcontext
public AppService : IService
{
  private readonly AppDbContext _ctx; 

  public AppService(DbContext context)
  { 
     // because the DI container have both the dbcontext and the appservice registered it knows how to resolve the dependencies for the service. 
     _ctx = context;
  }

  public void DoStuff()
  { 
    // _ctx is not null at this point.
  }
}

// DbContext class
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    // call to base constructor with options built from startup.cs class.
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options):base(options)
    {}
}
```

alternative model, for edgecase usage

```cs
// class that uses DbContext without using standard Dependency injection

public class AppService : IAppService 
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _ctx;

    public AppService()
    {
      _ctx = new AppDbContext(@"/*connectionstring here*/");
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
      // _ctx was during instantiation of class manually injected. 
    }
}

// DbContextClass
public class AppDbContext 
{
   public AppDbContext(string connectionString): base()
   {
     var builder = new DbContextOptionsbuilder<AppDbContext>();
     builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

     OnConfiguring(builder);
   }
}
```

but for your usecase it sounds like you shouldn't parse the context down to your hockeyplayerdata / repository from the controller, but more should register your hockeyplayer data to the servicecollection, and refer the data service in your controller. and have the container taking care of it. Also do not have a static reference to your DbContext. DbContext is by default registered with a Scoped Service Lifetime, and adding it as a singletong is a whole other level of confusion that can lead to concurrency issues.

```cs
// startup.cs onconfigure method 
services.AddScoped<HockeyPlayerData>();

// data repository 
public class HockeyPlayerData 
{
  
  private readyonly AppDbContext _ctx;
  public HockeyPlayerData(AppDbContext context)
  {
    _ctx = context;
  }

}

// in your controller 
public class MyController 
{
  private readonly HockeyPlayerData _dataService;
  public MyController(HockeyPlayerData dataService)
  {
    // again letting the DI container taking care of resolving services.
    _dataService = dataService;
  }
}
```